# How can I change rebass 'Text'(div) component to other semantic element?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-markup, rebass

The default HTML element for the Text component is div.
I'd like to change the Text component HTML element to other tags such as H1, H2, H3, and P for semantic.
How can I change the rebass Text component HTML element to other tags for semantic?

Answer (score 0):

Rebass Text component has "as" prop to support semantics.

```
<Text as="h1">Hello World</Text>
```